# Como le puedo poner delay a la funciones del Minecraft Bedrock Edition?

Tags: json, bucles, function

estoy aprendiendo a como crear complementos para el Minecraft Bedrock Edition y estoy en la parte de los archivos mcfunction e visto que en java usan el comando shedule pero son diferentes sintaxis e leído en la documentación del Minecraft sobre un archivo llamado [ticks.json](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-mx/minecraft/creator/documents/tickjsonintroduction) por lo q entendí si colocamos las funciones dentro del archivo json se repetirán como un bucle. alguien me puede explicar como ponerle el delay o tiempo de retraso a una funcion?

1. sintaxis java:
   schedule function <nombre_de_la_funcion> <tiempo_en_tics>
2. sintaxis bedrock:
   schedule on_area_loaded add ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ <nombre_de_la_funcion>

quiero aprender a colocarles delay a los archivos mcfunctions del minecraft bedrock

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!